# Compile an example c file as part of a larger make-based C project?

Tags: c, open-source, installation, makefile

I often find myself wanting to compile an example file included in  a larger makefile-based open source `c` project. Is there a uniform  best way to proceed?

I  can't just compile the one file using `gcc` because there are all sorts of headers and dependencies that the `c` file requires which are scattered about the project. Here is a concrete example:

[HOCR](http://hocr.berlios.de/install.html) [(google cache here)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a-SkjL1j8ZPUJ%3ahocr.berlios.de/install.html%20hocr.berlios.de&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com), is an open source  Hebrew language optical character recognition program that is primarily GTK based. I need a command-line only version. Amongst the source code (downloadable [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hocr/hocr_0.8.2.orig.tar.gz)), there is a command-line only example c file: `examples/hocr/hocr-cmd.c`   that does exactly what I want.

How do I compile the example file?

In the base directory I can run `./configure`, `make` and `make install` but as far as I can tell this doesn't actually compile the example file.

Also, in addition to the main `Makefile` I see a number of `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in` files. Are these relevant? Is there a general guiding principle to proceed? This is not the first time I've gotten stuck here.

For those who are interested, I am running Ubuntu 10 Lucid on VirtualBox Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in `Makefile` there is a target that builds either the specific file or the files in the directory. Find that target and make it. Additionally, there may be a separate `Makefile` in that directory or one of its parents that is used for building them.

.am and .in files are for autotools, which is the step before `./configure`. You should not need to modify them in normal use.

Comment: If it were true that the main Makefile compiles the example file that I am interested in, then wouldn't you expect running `make all` would also compile that file?

Comment: Not necessarily. I have seen instances where that is not the case.